Any difference between: "I'm sorry that this happened." AND "I'm sorry that this EVER happened."?
I know the meaning of ever meaning "at any time" used in questions and negative sentences. For example. "Have you ever done this or that"?
However when it comes to affirmative simple past sentences, I can't quite understand ever, because the senses in the dictionaries don't seem to work here. For example, check the following sentences:
I'm sorry that this happened.
I'm sorry that this ever happened.
The sentence with "ever" was said by a man on a TV show, when his consecutive lies were revealed one after the other, and he finally had to accept that he had done all those cheatings which he had denied in the beginning.
However, I didn't understand why he added "ever" in his sentence, while he could have simply said "I am sorry that this happened".
So, none of the senses in the dictionary ("always, all the time, in any way, at any time") seem to work with this sentence. None can replace "ever" in this sentence.
So I want to ask native english speakers, what kind of an effect, if any, does the word "ever" create on the meaning in affirmative simple past sentences?

None, really; it just adds emphasis.

This question is similar to: What is the meaning of "I ever do" in ths context?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Paraphrase: "Sorry. I wish it had never happened."  Expression of deep regret.  Although "happened" isn't quite owning it.  So it's more like regret that it turned into the mess he's in.

What's unclear about "I'm sorry that this happened in any way/at any time"? Consider all the parts of the definition.


I'm sorry that this happened.


I'm sorry that this ever happened.

The one and only difference here is "ever" between the two sentences.
'ever' has a wide variety of usages, but the basic concept of 'ever' is 'at any time until now' or the opposite (on some occasion; at some very moment) of 'never(on no occasion; not once)':
Not+ever forms Never
So the relationship between "at any time until now" and "on some occasion/at some very moment" should be foregrounded.
Considering the direct and/or presumable correlation of now, moment and occasion, we are given to unserstand that 'ever' might have the tone of voice "Why this occasion? NOW of all the times!; at this very moment happend an occasion that NEVER happend before)
In other words, the 'ever' in your example could mean "very now in any way"

I'm sorry that this ever[very now in any way] happened.


What is 'very now' supposed to mean?

something that never happend before: never before but ever now
